# Connect Android to device by Bluetooth: how to set pin without any passkey popup

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-button

I am not able to set pin to connect to a device by bluetooth.
This is my code:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver ActionFoundReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                callPairDevice(device);                                                     
            } else if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST.equals(action)) {             
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);                                       
                    setPin (device);                
            }
        }...
    };
```

> Method used to createBond

```
public boolean callPairDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
    try {

       btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Method createBond = BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("createBond");
        return (Boolean) createBond.invoke(device);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

> This method tries to set the pin:

```
public void setPin (BluetoothDevice device) {
   try {
        Method m = BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("setPin", byte[].class);
        byte[] pin = (byte[]) BluetoothDevice.class.getMethod("convertPinToBytes", String.class).invoke(BluetoothDevice.class, "1234");
        boolean isSetPin = (Boolean) m.invoke(device, pin);

        btSocket = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);           
        btSocket.connect(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("setPin()", e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Somebody can help me to find a solution?
Thanks a lot....

Comment: Try using:
CreateInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);